# PHP Unzip issue ZipArchive extractTo not creating Folders

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

when i'm extacting a zip-Archive that contains a subfolder with some Images in it, then the directory is not created. Instead the Directory-Name is now part of the filename ?!

This makes no sense to me at all?

ImageFiles\

- Image1.jpg
- Image2.jpg
- ...

The Result of extractTo would be a file in the root directory named
'ImagesFiles\Image1.jpg'

Any ideas on how to create this ImageFile folder when extracting the files ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I made a [quick demo](https://gist.github.com/cjhaas/47ed7448e3da9f1ea3a8f3396edd4453) and I'm seeing folders just fine. Can you post your code, along with a representative ZIP file?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and the demo code, it works totally fine in your demo. I figured out the problem has sth to do with the zip file. When i uncompress it on Windows and than compress it again the error is gone. But when i use the original zip file that i got from a supplier the error is still present.

Comment: I'm using shell_exec to inflate the file and there is a Warning - Message:  appears to use backslashes as path separators. So i guess this is the issue why ZipArchive is behaving link that. So the Problem lies in the ZipFile.